# Error while initializing Account in Solana

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I'm new to Solana development and I'm currently trying to initialize an Account using the following code:

```
import { 
    Connection, 
    Keypair, 
    PublicKey, 
    Transaction, 
    SystemProgram,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY
} from "@solana/web3.js";

import { 
    createInitializeAccountInstruction,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID 
} from "@solana/spl-token";

import bs58 from "bs58";

const secret = new Uint8Array(bs58.decode("..."));
const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secret);

async function main(signer=payer){
    const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
    const blockInfo = connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const transaction = new Transaction({
        recentBlockhash: (await blockInfo).blockhash,
    });

    const tokenAccount = Keypair.generate();
    console.log(bs58.encode(tokenAccount.publicKey.toBuffer()));
    const rent = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(165);

    const tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction = await SystemProgram.createAccount({
        newAccountPubkey: tokenAccount.publicKey,
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        lamports: rent,
        space: 165,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    });

    transaction.add(tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction);

    const initInstruction = createInitializeAccountInstruction(
        tokenAccount.publicKey,
        new PublicKey("4ThReWAbAVZjNVgs5Ui9Pk3cZ5TYaD9u6Y89fp6EFzoF"),
        signer.publicKey,
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    transaction.add( initInstruction );
    transaction.sign( signer);
    const response = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [signer, tokenAccount]);
    console.log(response);
};

main();
```

However, I encountered an error message that says:

````
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount',
    'Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2926 of 400000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction'
  ]```

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can fix it?

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
````

Comment: Hey. This is likely related to the mint address parameter which you passed the value `new PublicKey("4T..zoF")` to. Where is this value from?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've resolved the issue now. I apologize for leaving it as it was, not knowing how to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this error is being thrown because the Mint address you are providing ("4ThReWAbAVZjNVgs5Ui9Pk3cZ5TYaD9u6Y89fp6EFzoF") does not exist (and therefore not a valid Mint account owned by the token program).

So you have a few account here:

- Signer/Payer: this is the wallet that is creating a token account
- TokenAccount: this is the address of the new token account being created
- Mint: is the specific token type that the token account will utilize (e.g., wBTC, SAMO, mSOL, etc.).

The account you provided is not a Mint account (it's a standard System Account or wallet owned by the System Program, not the Token Program). You can see that [here](https://explorer.solana.com/address/4ThReWAbAVZjNVgs5Ui9Pk3cZ5TYaD9u6Y89fp6EFzoF?cluster=devnet).

Here's an [example](https://explorer.solana.com/address/EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v) (USDC) of a mint account (details about a specific token: address, supply, etc.)

I suspect if you replace your mint address with an existing devnet token mint (e.g., "[EofYstMevXcYTuNZ14gsJfVFtdFSBtShP3mr77rEqtZr](https://explorer.solana.com/address/EofYstMevXcYTuNZ14gsJfVFtdFSBtShP3mr77rEqtZr?cluster=devnet)") (a fake USDC coin), your script will run. Ultimately what you will have created is a fUSDC token account owned by your signer.

If you want to make your own token account you can do something like this:

```
import { 
    createMint,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
//...
     const newMint = await createMint(connection, signer, signer.publicKey, null, 2)
```

This will generate a new token mint that has 2 decimals.

Also, if you're just creating a simple token account, Solana has a program called the Associated Token Program that makes it a little easier to create token accounts associated with a user/wallet:

```
import { 
    createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotent
} from "@solana/spl-token";
//...
     await createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotent(connection, payer, mint, signer.publicKey)
```

This will ultimately create a token account (for token `mint` owned by your `signer`).

Token accounts are tricky when you're getting started--please follow-up if this doesn't work or if you have other questions.

Comment: this visual may be helpful: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-transfer-spl-tokens-on-solana#associated-token-accounts

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I followed your advice and it worked! The article you shared with me was informative and helped me understand the subject even better.Thank you so much for your kindness!